# How do i make create-react-app install all folders and files?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, package.json, npx

I am having this issue with create-react-app. Normally, the command works as usual, however, recently the src folder does not get created and the package.json file is missing lines that would normally be there. Here is what happens when i run npx create-react-app sql:

```
C:\Users\{hidden}>npx create-react-app sql
npx: installed 98 in 8.439s

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\{hidden}\sql.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
    
yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from             
installation.
info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from     
installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency     
"typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev ||     
>= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 15 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.0.3
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react-scripts@3.4.1
└─ react@16.13.1
info All dependencies
├─ @babel/helper-member-expression-to-functions@7.10.5
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-typescript@7.10.4
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@7.9.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.9.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.10.5
├─ @babel/preset-typescript@7.9.0
├─ babel-preset-react-app@9.1.2
├─ cra-template@1.0.3
├─ eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1
├─ react-dev-utils@10.2.1
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react-error-overlay@6.0.7
├─ react-scripts@3.4.1
├─ react@16.13.1
└─ scheduler@0.19.1
Done in 31.26s.
```

Also, here is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "sql",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cra-template": "1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  }
}
```

The command finishes here, it doesn't go past that last line whereas before it would. Im very confused and would appreciate any help, Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8088

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, i have already been through this thread and the problem still persists

Comment: why does it say `C:\Users\{hidden}>yarn create react-app sql` when you say you are using `npx create-react-app sql`

Comment: Hi, that is a mistake, however, whether i use npx or yarn the same error reoccurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what happened, but when i tried the next day it worked. It now works thankfully. PS. i deleted and installed create-react-app multiple times but i didn't restart my laptop, maybe that was it